# EL Empty Operator - Basics?

Tags: java, jsp, el

I've just been introduced to the `empty` operator (as well as EL in general), and it seems that I'm missing something very basic.
From what I've learned, `${empty obj}` returns **true** if `obj` is null, or is an empty string, array, Map, or Collection

Why then, does the following code:

```
<html>
  <head><title>EL Practice</title></head>
  <body>
    <% String x = "hello"; %>
    <%= x %>
    <br>${empty x}  
  </body>
</html>
```

Produce the following output?

```
hello 
true
```

Isn't x, in this case, non-null/empty?

Thanks,
Jeff

**Edit:**
I think I may have answered my own questions, although I'd love some clarification.
When the code is altered (see line 5) as follows:

```
<html>
  <head><title>EL Practice</title></head>
  <body>
    <% String x = "hello"; %>
    <% pageContext.setAttribute("x", "hello"); %>
    <%= x %>
    <br>${empty x} 
  </body>
</html>
```

The output is:

```
hello 
false
```

Does the `${empty obj}` only work for obj's set as attributes?

Answer (score 0):

The `empty` operator and all other JSP expression language operators have access to the following JSP implicit objects,

- applicationScope
- cookie
- header
- headerValues
- initParam
- pageContext
- pageScope
- param
- paramValues
- requestScope
- sessionScope

check [here](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/jsp/jsp_expression_language.htm) for more information about them